# Sylow p-subgroup is normal if and only if it is a characteristic subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

Take finite group $G$ with Sylow p-subgroup $P$. Then, prove that

$P \unlhd G \iff P$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G$.

I know how to show the $\impliedby$ direction (if characteristic, then normal) but can't think of how to prove $\implies$ (if normal, then characteristic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a Sylow subgroup is normal, then it is the unique subgroup of that order, i.e. if $P\triangleleft G$ then there is only one subgroup of order $|P|$ which implies $P$ is characteristic since automorphisms preserve orders of subgroups.